# How to consolidate two json result into one dataframe in scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a code that read an array of the json file location and read it using the spark read json function. But I am getting output like below one

My Output for the below following code:

```
+---+------+
|name  |age|
+---+------+
|John  |24 |
|Cammy |20 |
|Britto|30 |
+---+------+

+---+------+
|name  |age|
+---+------+
|George|23 |
|Mikle |15 |
+---+------+
```

Code:

```
val dataPath = dataArr(counter)("data").arr
if (dataArr(counter)("type").value.toString() == "json") {
  dataLocation.foreach(i => {
    val rdd = spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles(i.str)
    val JsonFormat = rdd.map(i => "[" + i._2.replaceAll("\\}.*\n{0,}.*\\{", "},{") + "]")    
    val jsonOutput = spark.read.schema(Schema.getSchema(name)).option("multiLine", true).json(JsonFormat).show()
})
```

But how to change the above code to get the below-expected output, which is I want the above output in single table/data frame

```
Expected output
    +---+------+
    |name  |age|
    +---+------+
    |John  |24 |
    |Cammy |20 |
    |Britto|30 |
    |George|23 |
    |Mikle |15 |
    +---+------+
```

And this is how my dataLocation array looks like:

```
    {
        "source": [
            {
                "name": "testPersons",
                "data": [
                "E:\\dataset\\2020-05-01\\",
                "E:\\dataset\\2020-05-02\\"
                ],
                "type": "json"
            },
{
                "name": "testPets",
                "data": [
                "E:\\dataset\\2020-05-01\\078\\",
                "E:\\dataset\\2020-05-02\\078\\"
                ],
                "type": "json"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of foreach.. Do a map operation..so you'll get a List of Dataframes ( ie one df for each json file).

then simply union them all-

```
// After map rather than foreach
val dflist : List[DataFrame] = ???
```

In your case it can be  -
( I used var, since I didn't want to re-write full code or deviate away from what you have written already... and scala doesn't have global variable syntax)

```
var dflist: List[DataFrame] = List[DataFrame]()

val dataPath = dataArr(counter)("data").arr
if (dataArr(counter)("type").value.toString() == "json") {
    dflist = dataLocation.map(i => {
    val rdd = spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles(i.str)
    val JsonFormat = rdd.map(i => "[" + i._2.replaceAll("\\}.*\n{0,}.*\\{", "},{") + "]")    
    spark.read.schema(Schema.getSchema(name)).option("multiLine", true).json(JsonFormat)
})
```

```
// createEmpty dataframe with your schema for zero value to FoldLeft
val emptyDF = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD[Row], schema) 

val finalDF = dflist.foldLeft(emptyDF )((x,y) => x.union(y))
```

Comment: what should be done here I am new to this   val dflist : List[DataFrame] = ???

Comment: I am facing one issue @ValaravausBlack, I want to create .createOrReplaceTempView in above example I have given only one set of an array of json data i.e (under source there is "name": "testpersons" and its content following that It will have another set like that  "name": "testpet") so i want to create temp view for both with the respective name key value

Comment: for dflist = dataLocation.map( its showing reassignment to val

Comment: I am getting two different tables with union data but i can't able to create a view for each table